# Decomposing a poset into directed subposets

Tags: set-theory, posets, reference-request

Let us say that a poset $P$ is $\mathbf{\kappa}$**-directed** iff every collection of fewer than $\kappa$-many elements in $P$ has an upper bound in $P$.  $P$ has the $\mathbf{\kappa}$ **chain condition** iff every antichain in $P$ has size less than $\kappa$.  Consider statements of the form:

> Every poset $P$ with the $\kappa$ chain condition is the union of fewer than $\kappa$-many $\kappa$-directed subposets.

For $\kappa = \omega$ the above holds, it is a theorem due to **M. Pouzet**.  The proof hinges on the following fact:

> If $P$ is well-founded and has the ccc, then the partial order of downwards-closed subsets of $P$, ordered by inclusion, is well-founded.

This fact follows from a simple application of Ramsey's theorem.  The following statement is not amenable to the same Ramsey-theoretic argument, and is in fact false:

> (False) If $P$ is well-founded and has the $\omega _1$-cc, then the partial order of downwards-closed subsets of $P$, ordered by inclusion, is well-founded.

Therefore, if we replace $\kappa = \omega$ with $\kappa = \omega_1$ in Pouzet's theorem, we can't apply the same proof.  However I've been told (by Todorcevic) that the following is in fact true:

> (CH) If $P$ has the $\omega _1$-cc, then it is a countable union of $\omega _1$-directed subposets.

**My question** is simply a reference request: does anyone know where I can find a proof of this statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at: S. Todorcevic, Directed sets and cofinal types.